# iconv() – how to detect offending character?

Tags: php, character-encoding, iconv

I use `iconv()` to convert CSV data from **UTF-8** to **Windows-1252**.

```
$converted = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252", $csvData);
```

In some cases, `iconv()` failed quietly, returning `false`.

I also tried using `//TRANSLIT` but `iconv()´ returns **false** here as well.

When i add the `//IGNORE` statement to the target charset, the conversion succeeds, but that means one or more character(s) got lost.

I can stick to `//IGNORE` but i would like to find out which character(s) are causing the problem.

How can i do this?

Comment: I think, you can work with string as char array and use iconv on char.

Comment: Thank you @VladLatish – it was obvious but i didn't think of it. Please post it as an answer. Using this approach i was able to identify the offending character.

Comment: Their *"I think"* wouldn't qualify as much of an answer.  If @VladLatish can't post an answer with enough context and code, then it won't serve anyone very much really.

Comment: Well let's help the man, allowing him to do it right and giving him some rep in the end. Also a legitimate answer doesn't necessarily need to contain any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was bad idea to work with string as char array (see question comments) because [php string type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> Internally, PHP strings are byte arrays. As a result, accessing or modifying a string using array brackets is not multi-byte safe, and should only be done with strings that are in a single-byte encoding such as ISO-8859-1.

So we can use `mb_substr` for utf-8 and work with symbols not bytes

```
error_reporting('E_ALL & !E_NOTICE');
$yourString = "test bad ☺ string";
$convertString = '';
$badChars = [];

if (iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252", $yourString) === false) {       
    for($i = 0, $stringLength = mb_strlen($yourString); $i < $stringLength; $i++) {
        $char = mb_substr($yourString, $i, 1);
        $convertChar = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252", $char);

        if ($convertChar === false) {
            $badChars[$i] = $char;
        } else {
            $convertString .= $convertChar;
        }   
    }
} else {
    $convertString = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252", $yourString);
}

var_dump($badChars, $convertString);
```

Result `array(1) { [9]=> string(3) "☺" } string(16) "test bad string"`

P.S. The next time I will give a more detailed answer with the code. My mistake