# strtolower() providing faulty character?

Tags: php, character-encoding, iconv

I use `strtolower()` to convert strings to lower-case. When later in the code these strings are converted from **UTF-8** to **ANSI** *(Windows-1252)* using `iconv()`, the function fails unless the `//IGNORE` statement is used.

I identified the offending character as the lower-case German *Umlaut* `ü`. However, prior to the `ü` being used, there is an upper-case `Ü`, which converts just fine. The difference is that the string containing the lower-case `ü` has been created using `strtolower()`.

Why does `strtolower()` give me inconvertible results or wrong encoding? How can this be remedied?

Comment: didn't you post something similar already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221756/iconv-how-to-detect-offending-character

Comment: Consider using [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php)

Comment: I did post my other question in regard on HOW TO DETECT the offending character. Now that i have found it and found the cause of the problem, i opened a new question to find out how to fix it. Totally different things. Downvote entirely unjustified, whoever did that. @pr1nc3 – read the contents of the questions. It's not a duplicate at all.

Comment: @SquareCat *"Now that i have found it and found the cause of the problem,"* - Either post an answer for it to mark it as solved, or delete it. Otherwise, it's still considered as being open.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Go read the question + comments. I am waiting for the commenter to post his answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) which supports multibyte chracters

```
// Tell the function what charset you are using as second param. 
echo mb_strtolower($str, 'UTF-8');
```